# Check if any bootstrap modal is open

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to check, if **any** bootstrap modal is currently open?

The reason behind: I want to deactivate certain keyhandler, if a modal is open.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: I already have seen solutions from the answers below. But this is not what I want. I want a general solution, which works for any bootstrap modal on the page.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using jquery, you can use this :

```
function isABootstrapModalOpen() {
    return $('.modal.in').length > 0;
}
```

Vanilla JS solution :

```
function isABootstrapModalOpen() {    
    return document.querySelectorAll('.modal.in').length > 0;
}
```

This solution works for any modal, not just a specific one.

**Edit**: the code above test if, at any given moment, a modal is open. As indicated in the other answers, if you want to disable an event handler the moment the modal is opened, you'll have to use the bootstrap events, like this :

```
// when any modal is opening
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // disable your handler
})

// when any modal is closing
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // enable your handler
})
```

You can also use isABootstrapModalOpen in your event handler, to test if the handler's code has to be executed (so you don't to enable/disable the handler each time a modal is opened/closed).

```
function eventHandler(e) {
  // if a modal is open
  if(isABootstrapModalOpen()) {
    // prevent the event default action
    e.preventDefault();
    // and exit the function now
    return;
  }

  // if a modal is not open
  // proceed to the rest of the handler's code 
}
```

Comment: check can be more simple `if($('.modal.in').length)`

Answer (score 3):

The Bootstrap modals fire events when opened. In your case, I'd suggest to bind an event to the `show.bs.modal` event and unbind your key handler event. Simple example:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // yadda yadda .unbind()
})
```

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals, scroll down to Events.

Comment: As much as I don't like the question, this is still a good answer so +1

Comment: Yes, but this for a specific modal. I want a general solution for this.

Comment: @Razer according to the docs: "Overlapping modals not supported - Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code." So either you have that custom code built in, or the scenario you're trying to fix not exist. If you do have it fixed, you could bind to `$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '*', function() { ... })`

Comment: Should be `$('.modal')` or `$(document)`instead of `$('#myModal')`.

Answer (score 2):

**Here take this:**

```
$(document).find('.modal').each(function(e) {

    var element = $(this);

    if ( (element.data('bs.modal') || {isShown: false}).isShown ) {
      console.log('a modal is open');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use jQueries's hasClass method.

```
return $('div.modal').hasClass('in'); // True if open, false if closed
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
alert($('#myModal').hasClass('in'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 the modal has class "show" if it is open

So to check if there is any modal open:

```
if ($('body').find('.modal.show').length) {
    // Do something
}
```

I currently use stacked modals (multiple open), and the problem was that if you do .modal('hide') of a single modal. Bootstrap removes the class .modal-body from the body element. And then the modal didn't scroll anymore so I had to do this:

```
$(document)
    .on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
        /**
         * Check if there are still modals open
         * Body still needs class modal-open
         */
        if($('body').find('.modal.show').length) {
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }
    })
;
```

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to this direct question, it is related.
Here's how to check if within a Bootstrap 4 modal:
`if (window.parent.jQuery('.modal-content').length > 0) { // in a modal }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    console.log("Modal is open");
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).